# vba code time stamp that doesnt change in excel

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I know I have made an obvious mistake somewhere but I initially tried to make a code that would put a timestamp in but then not overwrite it,  I initially had the first line at the end and it all compilled but no matter what it would change the time.  I would like once there is data in both the timereference cell and the target that the timestamp would not update.  Only if both cells were subsequently cleared.  Any help provided would be gratefully received.

```
Function Patienttime(reference As Range)
If reference.Value <> "" And IsEmpty(Patienttime) = False Then End If
ElseIf reference.Value <> "" And IsEmpty(Patienttime) = True Then
Patienttime = Format(Now, "HH:MM")
ElseIf IsEmpty(reference.Value) = True Then Patienttime = ""

End Function
```

Comment: Your last if branch does nothing, you need `Patienttime = Format(Now, "HH:MM")` in there, also there is no `end if`

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand your text and I don't understand your code!

Comment: Also, you have a function called `Patienttime` and a variable/range called the same??????/

Comment: Use Debug -> Compile VBAProject in the editor. This will give you a the compile errors. In this case, the `End If` at the end of the first line is misplaced.  Also `IsEmpty(Patienttime)` is testing the *return value* of the *function itself*. That means `IsEmpty(Patienttime)` is always `True` until you assign to it.

Comment: i feel I should explain a bit, it is meant to be a function that references a cell, if there is a name in that cell it will then populate the cell with the function patienttime with a time stamp.  If you have made a spelling mistake for example and change it, the time stamp is updated, I was trying to get the function to check if there is a name, and then to check if there is already a time, if there is already a time then to not change anything.

Comment: Make this explanation a part of your question! Change your code that it shows what you want to achieve or add a second code parts which shows what you want to achieve e.g with pseudocode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)! What are your inputs? Where should the output be?

Comment: The cell requiring a timestamp in this case A3 would have patienttime(C3)